# label text not changing from code behind

Tags: c#, ajax

I have ajax rating control and I am trying to capture its rated value in label.

code for rating control is :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upRating">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <act:Rating ID="rfixer" runat="server" CurrentRating="0" MaxRating="4" EmptyStarCssClass="emptypng" FilledStarCssClass="smileypng" StarCssClass="smileypng" WaitingStarCssClass="donesmileypng" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed">
      </act:Rating>
      <asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am changing text of label when rating is changed:

```
 protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    int iRate = Convert.ToInt16(e.Value);
    string strMessage = string.Empty;
    switch (iRate)
    {
        case 1:
            strMessage = "Not Useful";
            break;
        case 2:
            strMessage = "Average";
            break;
        case 3:
            strMessage = "Useful";
            break;
        case 4:
            strMessage = "Informative";
            break;
        case 5:
            strMessage = "Excellent";
            break;
    }
    strMessage = "Thanks for Rating, You found this Question " + strMessage;
    lblRating.Text = iRate.ToString();

   // e.CallbackResult = strMessage;

}
```

But text in label is never changed.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try changing the label to a hardcoded value, i.e on the first line of `Rating1_Changed` write `lblRating.Text = "Testing"; return;` that will make sure that `Rating1` causes a postback on change

Comment: you are missing `AutoPostBack=true`

Comment: If I change text of label from Page_Load it is getting changed but when I change it from Rating1_Changed, text is not changed.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - AutoPostback for which control?

Comment: @user1181942 for the Rating control `<act:Rating`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `AutoPostBack="true"` in your Rating  control

```
  <act:Rating ID="rfixer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CurrentRating="0" MaxRating="4" EmptyStarCssClass="emptypng" FilledStarCssClass="smileypng" StarCssClass="smileypng" WaitingStarCssClass="donesmileypng" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed">
  </act:Rating>
```

Comment: Thanks... This was stupid mistake I was doing... Thank you so much.. i am not able to mark this as answer right now..Will do it after some time